# Machine learning systems where there is a feedback loop between predictions and features

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

Say you have a machine learning model that predicts whether and online order for an item from a store will be successful.  If it is predicted to not be successful at a given time then the item is not shown on the website.  Now also consider that the model uses a feature that is the rate of unsuccessful orders for that item in the last 14 days.  Let's also say that the model was trained on a dataset where items are always shown.

So once the model is in production and an item is predicted to be unsuccessful it will not be shown.  But if it is not shown then it will affect the unsuccessful order input feature of the model.  So there is a feedback loop between the prediction and the input feature.  How is this case dealt with in machine learning?

Comment: One option (stepping one level up from ML to experimental design) is A/B testing: have some group of users that don't see the model's outputs, and keep those counts separate.